# How to log IF statement in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I made a logon PowerShell script to check files, if older than source then copy newer one to PC. I am trying to have the result logged but my log file is always empty. Where did I do wrong?

```
# Set Source
$S_P = "\\NETWORK\S_P.exe"
$S_T = "\\NETWORK\S_T.exe"
$S_P_Date = (Get-Item $S_P -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$S_T_Date = (Get-Item $S_T -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

# Set Destination
$D_P = "C:\TEMP1\S_P.exe"
$D_T = "C:\TEMP2\S_T.exe"
$DF_P = "C:\TEMP1"
$DF_T = "C:\TEMP2"
$D_P_Date = (Get-Item $D_P -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$D_T_Date = (Get-Item $D_T -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$D_Log = "C:\TEMP\updated.txt"

# Compare date and Copy
function Check_Copy {
    if (!(Test-Path $D_Log)) {New-Item $D_Log}

    if ((Test-Path $D_P) -and (Test-Path $D_T)) {
        if ($D_P_Date -le $S_P_Date) {Copy-Item $S_P $DF_P -Force}
        if ($D_T_Date -le $S_T_Date) {Copy-Item $S_T $DF_T -Force}
    } else {
        Copy-Item $S_P $DF_P -Force
        Copy-Item $S_T $DF_T -Force
    }
}

Check_Copy | Out-File $D_Log -Append
```

Comment: I believe I've mentioned before that using `robocopy` is a much easier way to replicate files than trying to script if yourself (particularly if you're not pretty familiar with PowerShell).

Comment: Why you are stopping people from learning? what is wrong with me using powershell? I am hoping to get answers from people who knows better than me. I think that's the purpose of people asking questions here.

Comment: If you think my question is too easy for you, you dont have to answer it. I am in the process of learning powershell, I have questions, so I ask.

Comment: My intent wasn't to antagonize but rather to point out that you are wasting a lot of effort. If you're still learning PowerShell, I would start with something less ambitious to make sure you understand the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the PassThru Parameter for the output to be piped out to your file. Otherwise, the output is hidden.

Simply add it to your Copy-Item lines so that it looks like this:

```
Copy-Item $S_P $DF_P -Force -PassThru
Copy-Item $S_T $DF_T -Force -PassThru
```

Read [this TechNet blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/11/18/use-the-powershell-passthru-parameter-and-get-back-objects/) to learn more about using object pass through in PowerShell.

Comment: ok, I see `copy-item` is in the log, what if I want to log the result of `If`?

Comment: I think `Start-Transcript` & `Stop-Transcript` could be better way to do it.